# How does an app efficiently figure out which users have each other in their phone contacts? Eg WhatsApp, Telegram, Viber

Tags: android

My question may sound stupid when first read but let me explain.

Jim and Fred.

Jim signs up to WhatsApp through SMS verification. Fred signs up too. Without having added each other through a process of exchanging usernames, Fred and Jim appear in the list of phone contacts that have WhatsApp.

Do both phones upload their entire contact database and they are compared? If so then does this have to happen regularly to update the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the application. Most applications simply upload the phone's contact database to the service's server and checks, if they are registered there.

There is also the possibility of creating a value from a contact and upload that to check if the person is registered (much like a hash).

**Please note** that uploading a person's contact database is a privacy issue so the second method may be preferred. If you plan on doing this yourself, include a note in the App's description as well!